# Как запретить следующему блоку менять размеры?

Tags: javascript, html, css, design, дизайн

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю, что тут вообще не так. При нажатии на кнопку выпадает список, как и положено, но див ниже сжался размером. Код дива, который ниже:

```
display:flex;
justify-content:space-beetwen;
width:100% - 2vw;
align-items:center;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `flex: 0 0 100%;` - Эта строчка задает:

`flex-grow: 0;` - запрещает элементу увеличиваться по ширине.

`flex-shrink: 0;` - запрещает элементу сжиматься по ширине.

`flex-basis:100%;` - задает ширину в 100%

`width:100%;` в flex не работает.

И математику (если используете) помещайте в calc();

```
flex:0 0 calc(100% - 2vw);
```

Если вы пытаетесь так сделать отступы по бокам, то лучше задайте padding для контейнера.